# UITableViewCell animation bug in `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` while using `estimatedRowHeight` and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

When using `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` to move a `UITableViewCell`, I'm seeing an animation glitch when using `estimatedRowHeight` and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` when the cell animates from a visible state to a non-visible state.

The issue disappears if I explicitly set the height of cells by implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. The issue only appears when the source and destination index paths are visible and non-visible, respectively. When the cell is moving to another visible index path, the animation behaves as expected.

I've created a sample project to illustrate the effect: https://github.com/timarnold/Table-Cell-Sizing-Bug

http://www.openradar.me/19156703

## Edit

@rdelmar pointed out that my question doesn't actually ask a question.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this bug and fix this behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

## Edit 2014-12-08

I used one of my Apple-provided developer support tickets to inquire about this issue with Apple. They confirmed that it was a bug (visit http://www.openradar.me/19156703 to dupe) and didn't provide any workarounds.

Comment: You know how to fix this, so what's your question? I think this is a case of "you get what you pay for" (the pay being time and code complexity). This, and problems with scrolling to a particular indexPath are the consequence of the way estimated heights are used, so I don't think you can fix it (it will be interesting to see if Apple can fix it either without sacrificing the speed benefit of using estimated heights). You could probably minimize the effect by providing a more accurate estimate of your heights (though that won't help much if you have widely varying heights).

Comment: Well, it's not so much a question as it is a documentation of the problem and a request for potential work-arounds (I guess my request should be more explicit; will edit the question). I do think it's fair to categorize this behavior as a bug, however, since the project to reproduce is fairly simple and uses all stock components and capabilities.

Comment: I don't know whether I would call it a bug, or just the consequence of the trade off between speed and correctness that Apple has made. It's a technique that will work for some cases, but not all. I think the only work around, is to calculate the heights the "old-fashioned" way -- I hope I'm wrong about that, because the new self-sizing cells are great when they work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this couldn't pretty easily be fixed. We know the size of the cell that is moving to a non-visible index path. We know the content offset of the cells surrounding the cell that was just removed. Couldn't we then orchestrate the animation such that this doesn't happen, even not knowing all the heights of the non-visible cells?

Answer (score 1):

Try to cache cell heights.

```
private var cellHeights = [NSIndexPath: CGFloat]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let cachedHeight = cellHeights[indexPath] {
        return cachedHeight
    } else {
        return 60
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tim,

This is not a definitive answer but some interesting findings. Rather than a bug I believe the behavior you're experiencing is related to the way iOS draws cell on the device screen. More specifically, to the cells that are off the screen. Since, the data source is not affected by cells reordering iOS lose track of the cell position.

To make my point clearer I have made the following modifications to `TableViewController.m`:

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                          toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-3 inSection:indexPath.section]];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row + 1];
```

You'll see that cells misbehave only when moving to a position outside of the screen view. Additionally,  cells are redrawn each time you move the screen.

Comment: What's the difference between a 'bug' and 'behavior you're experiencing' not matching the expected behavior that the documentation says should happen?

Comment: @AnthonyMattox your question is not clear. I've never referred to a documentation. I was testing the code.